# How to store blanched garlic?

Tags: storage-method, garlic, blanching

I've gone through the process of immersing my garlic in boiled water 3 times to remove that bitter taste. But how do I store it? I've blanched close to 5 heads of garlic (40-ish cloves). I would rather not pickle it. Any advice?

Answer (score 4):

Once you blanch garlic it needs to be treated as cooked, so if you don't want to pickle it then your options are to refrigerate it or freeze it.

Comment: And refrigerating will work for a similar amount of time as any other cooking vegetable, so 3-5 days.

Comment: Neither option is that great for that amount of blanched garlic really, refrigeration doesn't preserve it long enough to use it all, and freezing is going to destroy part of the flavor. @codeninja is better off not blanching that much in the first place.

Comment: how should i refrigerate it? Suspend in oil? Water? As is?

Comment: Just put it into an airtight container, oil or water isn't going to do much.

Comment: And in fact, putting it in oil is positively dangerous, as it provides a nice anoxic environment for _botulinum_ to grow in.